# Cannot Get Xdmx to work with two Ubuntu Computers (xinit error)

Tags: networking, xorg, display, xinit, xdmx

I have two computers running Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity, and I'd really like to use the distributed multihead (Xdmx) software in order to use one of the computers as a second monitor, instead of just using two computers with Synergy. I replicated this error at work and home (I have two computers each location). First, on both machines I installed Xdmx:

```
sudo apt install xdmx
```

On the slave, I added the line `xserver-allow-tcp=true` at the end of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to get slave to listen to host so that the host can grab its display. I then restart slave in order to have this take effect. On both machines, just to be safe, in order to let the X screen be grabbed, I do

```
xhost +
```

In order to make sure that slave is listening to host and I can grab the X display from host, I type on host `telnet 192.168.99.20 6000` and it works (`192.168.99.20` is the IP address of slave). Finally, on host I do

```
startx -- /usr/bin/X11/Xdmx :1 -display :0 -display 192.168.99.20:0 -ignorebadfontpaths +xinerama -norender
```

Both screens go black for a few seconds, and then come back on and I see a lot of output, with the error at the end:

```
xinit: XFree86_VT property unexpectedly has 0 items instead of 1  
xinit: connection to X server lost  

waiting for X server to shut down  
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Any help or suggestions you have would be amazing, thanks!